How do I send the entire search from Splunk to Pagerduty
We have a Splunk alert set up. The alert goes to Pagerduty. The issue is the search that triggers the alerts has multiple columns and rows but we see only one row in the PagerDuty. We want the entire results list to be sent. We tried a custom message but it comes up empty. The search result look like this :
perc  label
0.06    0
0.03    NOK-NOK
1.47    NOK-OK
98.44   OK
This is a dynamic result that is sometimes just one row. We want to send the entire search result to PD.
The custom message renders as empty:
{"Results ":"$job.table$"}

You can't create a random token and expect anything to come out of it.  For a list of recognized Job tokens, see https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.2.1/Search/ViewsearchjobpropertieswiththeJobInspector#Search_job_properties
